# Oracle insert query returned error 01843. 00000 - "not a valid month"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute below query.

```
INSERT INTO X_VW_PRICEPRODUCT_IC
     SELECT * FROM ER_PRICEPRODUCT@link;
```

IN `X_VW_PRICEPRODUCT_IC` I have relevant two columns with `DATE` data type.
And there are two columns in ER_PRICEPRODUCT having values like `01-01-1900` and `01-01-1900`

When I execute this sql I get error `01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"`

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-01843 not a valid month- Comparing Dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157224/ora-01843-not-a-valid-month-comparing-dates)

Comment: @alfasin  this is not selecting specific date range. I want everything in the table to copy to other table.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Your problem is trying to use varchar and enter it a a date. Try to run `describe X_VW_PRICEPRODUCT_IC` and then `describe ER_PRICEPRODUCT@link` and compare the outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle will not automatically convert dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy to a date.  You need to explicitly use `to_date()`.  Although, it is a good idea to include column names in an `insert`.  Something like:

```
insert into X_VW_PRICEPRODUCT_IC(col1, . . . )
    SELECT col1, . . ., to_date(datecol, 'MM-DD-YYYY), . . .
    FROM ER_PRICEPRODUCT@link;
```

Answer (score 0):

The date-strings of the remote table seems to be in the format 'dd-mm-yyyy'. So, you have to change the date interpretation of strings for your session:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy';
```

Then execute your statement.